# When I search something in search box , the keyword which I entered disappears after giving the result

Tags: php

I have an ideal search-box which searches item from a given listing. My searching is working fine, the problem is when I enter something in search box to search, it gives me result but my search box gets empty.
For eg If I search "Electronics" in search box, it gives me result of electronics but my search box gets empty. It should be written with "Electronic" when it gives me result.
Probably, I should be using GET method instead is it so?

Here is my code for searching:

```
    <form action="" method="post">  

                Search: <input type="text" name="term" /><br />  
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
            </form>  

if (!empty($_REQUEST['term']))
 {

    $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_name  LIKE '%" . $term . "%' or parent LIKE '%" . $term . "'  or cat_status LIKE '%" . $term . "'";
}
$r_query = mysql_query($sql);
if ($r_query > 1) 
{

$dynamicList="";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)) 
    {
        // $cat_id=; 
         /*$dynamicList .= '
          <img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="../storeadmin/category/thumbs/' . $row['cat_id'] . '.jpg" width="77" />';*/
        echo "<tr bgcolor=''>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cat_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><img style='border:#666 1px solid;' width='70' src='http://localhost/jaymin/My%20Store/storeadmin/category/thumbs/". $row['cat_id'].".jpg' /></td>";

        //echo "<td>".$dynamicList."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cat_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['parent'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cat_status'] . "</td>";

        echo "<td><a href='categoryylisting_edit.php?id=" . $row['cat_id'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a name='delete' href='categoryylisting_edit.php?id=" . $row['cat_id'] . "'>Delete</a></td><tr>";



        echo "</tr>";
    }
} 
else {
    echo "Nothing should be displayed";
}
?>
        </table>
```

Comment: The reason is that once the form is submitted, the page is refreshed. Thus whatever you typed before is deleted. If you wanna keep it, you could use php to re-generate the value of the input box. like this     
`<input type="text" name="term" value="<?php echo $_POST['term']; ?>" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to

```
Search: <input type="text" name="term" value="<?php echo @$_REQUEST['term']; ?>" /><br />
```

instead of

```
Search: <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
```

Comment: never use $_REQUEST if you know it should be POST\GET

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<input type="text" name="term" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['term'])){ echo $_POST['term']; } ?>"/>
```

If you want this in your `url` use `GET` instead of `POST` like,

```
        <form action="" method="get">  
            Search: <input type="text" name="term" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['term'])){ echo $_GET['term']; } ?>" /><br />  
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are submitting the form and after form submit textbox values disappears. To overcome this try:

```
<input type="text" name="term" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['term'])){ echo $_POST['term']; } ?>"/>
```